# else: statement syntax error, simple Python

Tags: python, if-statement

My second else: statement is throwing up a syntax error, any idea why?

This is code for checking for sideswap numbers:

```
number1 = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 9")) 
number2 = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 9"))
number3 = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 9"))


X = number1 + number2 + number3

while True:
        if X%3 !=0:
            print("Not a valid sideswap number")
            number1 = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 9"))

            number2 = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 9"))

            number3 = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 9"))

        else:
            if number2 - number3 == 1:
                print("Not a valid sideswap number")
                number1 = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 9"))

                number2 = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 9"))

                number3 = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 9"))

        else:           
            if number3 - number1 == 1:
                print("Not a valid sideswap number")
                number1 = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 9"))

                number2 = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 9"))

                number3 = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 9"))

        else:
            if number1 - number2 == 1:
                print("Not a valid sideswap number")
                number1 = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 9"))

                number2 = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 9"))

                number3 = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 9"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
else:
    if number2 - number3 == 1:
```

the expression is

```
elif number2 - number3 == 1:
```

have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements):

> ```
> >>> if x < 0:
> ...     x = 0
> ...     print 'Negative changed to zero'
> ... elif x == 0:
> ...     print 'Zero'
> ... elif x == 1:
> ...     print 'Single'
> ... else:
> ...     print 'More'
> ```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like `else if` in python. Use `elif`

For example:

```
else:           
    if number3 - number1 == 1:
```

Change this to:

```
elif number3 - number1 == 1:
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple `else` for the same `if`. What you are looking for is `elif:` . Example -

```
while True:
        if X%3 !=0:
            print("Not a valid sideswap number")
            number1 = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 9"))

            number2 = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 9"))

            number3 = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 9"))

        elif number2 - number3 == 1:
                print("Not a valid sideswap number")
                number1 = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 9"))

                number2 = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 9"))

                number3 = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 9"))

        elif number3 - number1 == 1:
                print("Not a valid sideswap number")
                number1 = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 9"))

                number2 = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 9"))

                number3 = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 9"))

        elif number1 - number2 == 1:
                print("Not a valid sideswap number")
                number1 = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 9"))

                number2 = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 9"))

                number3 = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 9"))
```